# Navigator.GeoLocation.getCurrentPosition enable location after it was previously denied - iOS Chrome and Safari

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, navigator

Is there a way I can enable the "Share Location" on the mobile browser after I have denied access to my location? Even if I given all the permissions to use my location, I still get the PERMISSION_DENIED error from Navigator.GeoLocation.getCurrentPosition

Please Note:

1. Setting >> Privacy >> Location Services - On (checked)
2. Settings >> Chrome >> Location - While Using the App (checked)

Comment: Hey, did you got any solution for this?